# How to calculate hexadecimal multiplication?

Tags: java

How can I make the Java code to calculate hexadecimal multiplication? (Just 8bit length.)

For example I have hexadecimal `ab` and `05`, And `F0 * 02  = fb` (maybe).

But I don't know why the answer is `fb`.

Could you teach me how to make this with java code?

Comment: Step 1 is to learn how to convert between hex and decimal (first by hand, then in code).

Comment: What do you mean by 8 bit length? do you want to store in only 8 bit the result?

Answer (score 1):

By hand, hexadecimal is *base-16*, so:

```
    Hex   Decimal
base 16   base 10
      0 =  0
      1 =  1
      2 =  2
       ...
      9 =  9
      A = 10
      B = 11
      C = 12
      D = 13
      E = 14
      F = 15
```

so the hexadecimal value `AB` is `((A = 10) * 16) + (B = 11))` or `160 + 11 == 171`.

Bringing "8 bits" into the picture, a single `byte` (by convention these days, an *octet*) is made up of 8 bits.  Eight bits is enough to represent 256 unique values, and in *unsigned* form represents values 0-255 decimal, or `0x00` to `0xFF` hexadecimal.  You may notice that this means that any 8-bit value can be represented by *exactly two(2)* hexadecimal digits.

In code, you can use `0x` prefix to enter literals in hexadecimal notation.

```
int answer = 0xF0 * 0x02;
System.out.printf("%x%n", answer);
```

A [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (or similar, like `System.out.printf`) can convert a result back into hex easily enough.  But if this is for a homework assignment, your instructor won't like this answer.

Comment: he has a weird requirment "8 bit length"... difficult to cope with it.

Comment: @Alboz edited with an attempt to explain the relationship in general.  My answer is not attempting to solve any specific case.